# Is there a good tool to get the sd-card out better?

Tags: sd-card

Is there a good tool to get the sd-card out better?

So that I don't damage the sd-card?
And also not the sd-card slot

I did take a tweezer from metal. It can damage the sd-card

Comment: It is called a fingernail

Answer (score 1):

Some of the old Pi models had 'spring loaded' SD card holders but to save costs, these have been removed from a lot of them now so if pushing in and releasing does not help then the best things I have found are plastic flat end tweezers.

These are normally sold on electronic markets (Ali / eBay / Digikey etc) as anti-static but a search for *plastic flat ended tweezers* works in English.

Do not pay too much for them - some sellers charge a fortune for them...

Answer (score 0):

If it's an older model Pi just push it in and then it pops out half way making removal with fingers easy.

Comment: This is not true for newer models. They replaced the spring fit SD card slot with a friction slot a while ago.

Comment: My mistake, I just happened to have a Pi2 in front of me when I answered and assumed they'd all be the same. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely pull out the SD card with regular metal pliers without damaging anything. Just don't push on the handles too hard and don't use oversized tools for something as small as an SD card.

Many other tools will work just fine. For instance, I have a pair of forceps which are great for holding tiny parts together while soldering: these would work too. I would only buy a special tool if I was charged with a task involving pulling out hundreds of SD cards per day.

Answer (score 0):

On most SDCards, there is a bump at the end which you can pull it from.